# React Native Material Bottom Installation Error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install **React Native Material Bottom Tab Navigator**, But I am getting error which I have attached below. I am unable to understand it.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1rvr.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem, I have just upgraded npm by below code and it started working.

```html
npm i -g npm-upgrade
```